# Imprimir los datos de un JSON en una tabla con php

Tags: php, json

tengo este resultado JSON y quiero pasarlo a una tabla en con PHP

`{"estado":1,"mensaje":"Datos Correctos","datos":{"nombre":"Juan","folio":"1934"}}`

La tabla se debe mostrar de la sig. manera

| estado | mensaje   | nombre | folio |

|   1    | Datos ... | Juan   | 1934  |

Tengo el siguiente codigo, pero el foreach no me muestra las llaves "nombre" y "folio"

```
<?php
$datos = json_decode(file_get_contents('URL'), true);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> TABLA </title>
</head>
<body>
    <table width="70%" border="1px" align="center">

    <tr align="center">
        <?php 
        foreach($datos as $k => $v) { ?>
        <td> <?php echo $k; ?> </td>
       <?php  } ?>
       
    </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $datos["estado"]?></td>
                <td><?php echo $datos["mensaje"]?></td>
                <td><?php echo $datos["datos"]["nombre"]?></td>
                <td><?php echo $datos["datos"]["folio"]?></td>
            </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: En tu estructura del archivo JSON tienes como llave `nombre` pero en el código PHP lees ese dato con la llave `name`. Debes tener en cuenta eso. También si es posible y puedes compartir el archivo que obtienes con `file_get_contents()` para que podamos ofrecerte una solución.

Comment: Cierto! Gracias ya pude resolverlo con ayuda de las respuestas que me brindaron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo que siempre hagas una prueba de los objetos con los que estés trabajando para analizar su estructura.

Si escribes esto: `var_dump($datos);` verás algo así:

```
array(3) {
  ["estado"]=>
  int(1)
  ["mensaje"]=>
  string(15) "Datos Correctos"
  ["datos"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["nombre"]=>
    string(4) "Juan"
    ["folio"]=>
    string(4) "1934"
  }
}
```

Tenemos un array con tres elementos, donde uno de esos elementos es **otro array anidado** bajo la clave `datos`, que es el array que contiene los valores para `nombre` y para `folio`.

Eso significa que la lectura tiene que cambiar. En tu `foreach` actual los valores se imprimirían `N` veces repetidas, donde `N` es la cantidad de elementos del array, porque en realidad no estás diferenciando los elementos. Además, debes determinar cuando el valor de `$k` sea  `datos`, para imprimir en ese momento los valores anidados. Por cierto, estabas usando una clave `name`, la cual no existe, la clave se llama `nombre` según muestras.

Finalmente, evita la horrible mezcla de código PHP/HTML, que produce un código confuso y difícil de analizar. Propongo un código escrito en todo PHP, concatenando.

Como opción, también podrías crear los encabezados de tablas de forma dinámica, como se muestra en el código.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title> TABLA </title>
        </head>
        <body>

    <?php
    
        $datos = json_decode(file_get_contents('URL'), true);
        #Columnas obtenidas de forma dinámica
        $columns=array_merge(array_keys($datos),array_keys($datos['datos']));
        
        #Quitamos la columna datos, que no interesa para este caso
        unset($columns[2]);
        
        #Construimos los encabezados de la tabla
        $th = "<tr align=\"center\"><th>".implode("</th><th>", $columns)."</th></tr>";
        
        $table="<table width=\"70%\" border=\"1px\" align=\"center\">";
        $table.=$th;
        $table.="<tr>";
        
        foreach ($datos as $k=>$v){
            if ($k!=="datos") {
                $table.="<td>$v</td>";
            } else {
                $table.="<td>".$datos["datos"]["nombre"]."</td>";
                $table.="<td>".$datos["datos"]["folio"]."</td>";
            }
        }
        $table.="</tr>";
        $table.="</table>";
        echo $table;    
    ?>
        </body>
    </html>
```

La salida de este código será una tabla como esta:

```html
<table width="70%" border="1px" align="center">
  <tr align="center">
    <th>estado</th>
    <th>mensaje</th>
    <th>nombre</th>
    <th>folio</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Datos Correctos</td>
    <td>Juan</td>
    <td>1934</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Si observas, los `tr` de los datos se construyen fuera del bucle, porque el ejemplo que estás poniendo es un objeto simple. Si en tu respuesta hay más de un objeto deberías poner un ejemplo con datos que incluyan al menos dos objetos, pues puede que esta parte del código, en ese caso, varíe un poco.

Comment: Diria que te has confundido, si hace el var_dump($datos) le da objetos en lugar de arrays (eso si el string en json que pone al principio es lo que intenta con el json_decode). Es lo que ha mi me ha salido cuando lo probé antes.

Comment: @masterguru no. Si observas, está pasando `true` en `json_decode`, ese `true` indica que quiere un array, no un objeto, para objeto se llama `json_decode` con ese segundo parámetro en `false`. Revisa el [apartado **associative** en el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php), donde está explicado lo que acabo de decir.

Comment: Pues va ser que tienes razón :-)  No me habia ni fijado en mis pruebas. Gracias por la aclaración.